# Can't do Mysql dump from google cloud composer

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create a simple dag that dumps mysql to a bucket like this:

```
extract = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='extract_data',
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_instance_connection',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_storage_default',
    sql='SELECT * FROM guestbook.entries',
    bucket='gs://bucketname',
    filename='guestbook.dump',
    dag=dag)
```

I create a MySQL connection called `mysql_instance_connection` with the ip address for the host, database name for the schema, login and password that I setup when creating the database online, and port as 3306.

When I run the dag I get the following error:

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '[IP_ADDRESS]' (110)")@-@{"task-id": "extract_data", "execution-date": "2018-08-21T16:35:59.161183", "workflow": "extractMysqlData"}`

What do I need to do to give composer permission to access my MySQL database?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine I've gone through this tutorial and still can't figure out how to get airflow to connect through the proxy

Comment: Rob, I understand you are running Google Cloud Composer in Kubernetes? It's what I understand from your last comment but you didn't mentioned this in your original message. May you specify where and how exactly are you trying to connect?

Comment: I also understand it is a Cloud SQL Second Generation instances, right?

Comment: I am trying to create a dag that uses my cloudsql instance

Comment: I mentioned it in the title of my post

Comment: I am trying to connect using `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`

Comment: Are there any errors logged in Stackdriver? You mentioned going through the tutorial, was there a specific point it stopped working?

Comment: @Rob did you manage to get this to work?